# How should I read and use data from a ~40GB csv for time series prediction?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I have a ~40GB csv file with data about taxi rides from 2013-2016 (approx. 105 million rows), using which I am trying to forecast revenue for the year 2017. Currently, I am testing techniques such as random forests, xgboost and Prophet. I have only been working with a small subset of the data because of memory constraints and now I need to do my predictions using all the data available.

What would be the best way to read all this data for forecasting purposes: will dask fit the purpose? For the smaller subsets, I used pandas, and I am currently looking into dask for reading the full data. Once I read the data in, I need to do rearranging operations like sorting them by date, computing the daily/weekly medians of some of the data, etc. Even while using dask, wouldn't it need to keep all the data in memory for doing the prediction?

Comment: It says: "Dask today to scale computations on their laptop, using multiple cores for computation and their disk for excess storage." on their site, so you can always give it a shot. I doubt it's going to be quick though, but I also doubt the the next 50 million entries are going to make a huge difference on the prediction (assuming random selection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will attempt to extract what I deem to be the important part of your question:

> is Dask useful for rearranging operations like sorting them by date, computing the daily/weekly medians of 40GB of CSV data?

*Short answer*: "yes"

Dask is built to break your data in chunks, so that you can implement pandas functionality on datasets that are larger than your available memory. It will sensibly accumulate only the data that you require for the output you are trying to achieve. A good portion of the pandas API is implemented, so you may be able to do what you want with very little change to the code you are using on the smaller datasets

Example, weekly averages of some column:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(...)  # same keywords as for the pandas variant
df = df.set_index('my_time_column')  
df['my_values'].resample('1w').mean().compute()
```